# Advance Job Sheduler for ISeries

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I use INavigor system for ad-hoc data extraction from the DB2 database. Only issue is that when it comes to automation. Is there a way I could automate the SQL code to be run on a specific time? I know there is Advance Job Sheduler but I'm not sure how the SQL can be added to the Sheduler. Any one who can help?

Comment: ...there are both paid and free reporting tools from a number of vendors that will work with (almost) any database and have scheduling capabilities, you're not necessarily locked to just the on-the-box utilities.  You might check with whoever bought your licenses, you may have something from IBM already.

Comment: Any reason the answer from Charles was not accepted? Perhaps the scheduled work must be the actual iNav Run SQL script feature initiating the script [with a query]? If so, then look into a client-based scheduler, or send a request/command to a client [capable of running the iNav] from the IBM i as server [using the AJS or standard JOBSCDE] that requests the process start [if, of course, the iNav client supports such an invocation versus activation merely by user requests made to the GUI].

Answer (score 0):

IBM added a [Run SQL Statements (RUNSQL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafyrunsql.htm?lang=en) CL command at v7.1.

Prior to that, you could store SQL statements in source files and run them with the [Run SQL Statements (RUNSQLSTM)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/runsqlstm.htm?lang=en) command.

Neither of the above allow an SQL Select to be run by itself.  For data extraction, you'd want `INSERT INTO tbl (SELECT <...> FROM <...>)`

For reporting SELECTs, your best bet is to create a Query Manager query (*QMQRY object) and form (*QMFORM object) via Start DB2 UDB Query Manager (STRQM); which can then be run by the Start Query Management Query (STRQMQRY) command.  Query Manager (QM) is SQL based, unlike the older Query/400 product.  QM manual is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzatc/sc415212.pdf)

One last option, is the [db2 utility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahz/rzahzdb2utility.htm) available via QShell.

Comment: don't enable the user.  This is not how business works.

Comment: @danny117 It's how many (most?) good businesses work. It's the users' data and they should be able to access it however their job requires.

Answer (score -3):

Don't waste effort creating a day late going out of business because the job scheduler hasn't updated the file system.

**Real businesses need real time data.**

Just make a SQL view on the iseries that pulls the info you need together.
Query the view externally in real time.  Even if you need last 30 days or last month or year to date.  These are all simple views to create.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.  You're making an assumption that OP is trying to run some sort of reporting.  I've got scheduled SQL statements that run updates/inserts.  Even if the OP does want a report, you're assuming there's no valid reason.

Comment: It's also assuming that 1) the data is already all present, and 2) that it's of a size that can be reasonably queried.

Comment: It simply doesn't answer the question, though the question probably needs more detail. If it's `ad hoc extraction`, then it isn't quite the same as 'ad hoc view creation'. Or it might be, with more detail.

Comment: Any business that doesn't report in real time is a target for a short sale and should be devalued by 40%.  Let's make it happen.